# Дощатой или досчатой?

Tags: орфография

Объясните пожалуйста как будет правильнее: "дощатой" или "досчатой" и почему?

Answer (score 3):

ДОЩАТОЙ. Буква щ пишется на конце корня в словах и формах с чередованиями ск — щ, ст — щ, напр.: ищу (ср. искать), прощу, прощённый, прощать (ср. простить), вощаной (воск), дощатый (доска), площе (плоский), гуще (густой), проще (простой), хлеще (от хлёсткий при отсечении согласнойк; ср. хлёстче). Однако в слове песчаный (от песок, песка) звук щ передается сочетанием букв сч. То же в слове тысчонка (от тысяча).
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=43
.Здесь чередование в пределах одной морфемы.

Чередование может происходить только в пределах корня, приставки или суффикса.

Comment: *Тыща*/*тыщонка*, так тоже пишут.

Comment: Скорее говорят, а на письме лишь передают разговорный вариант произношения.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что *ты{сч}онка* - правильный вариант произношения? А загляните в словарь Резниченко. Песок - не исключение из правила, так как в этом слове суффикс **ок**.
> Однако в слове песчаный (от песок, песка) **звук щ** передается сочетанием букв сч. То же в слове тысчонка (от тысяча).

Comment: неточно выразилась: разговорный вариант,произношение- т.е. просто запись произношения, но в литературном языке слова ТЫЩОНКА нет

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что суффикс -ОК?У Текучёва,Тихонова и Потихи корень песок, песч-, исторически тоже всё слово корень.Это у Валгиной почему-то  написано, что суффикс, не пойму почему.

Comment: Есть слово *су/песь*

Comment: Чередование может происходить только в пределах корня, приставки или суффикса. Например, в корне слов вощаной, дощатый, дощаник пишется щ, так как эта буква закономерно появляется на месте сочетания ск, входящегo в корень (воск, доск-а); в словах же брусчатый, песчаный пишется сч, так как это сочетание возникает на стыке корня и суффикса (брус-ок, пес-ок), а чередование происходит только в суффиксе: к - ч; ср.: мощ-ёный (мостить), кущ-ение (куст-иться)...
[Ссылка](http://nashol.com/2012011562890/pravopisanie-soglasnih.html)

Comment: Да видела я это, поначалу сама купилась, но потом поразмышляла, по словарям побегала - везде "песок"-корень, а в слове супесь - усечение основы, корня, такое бывает. А "супесчаная" как разберёте - су/пес/ч/ан/ая? Так не бывает суфф.-ч-.

Answer (score 0):

Простая, дощатая дверь на вершине...
Юрий Караулов
Простая,дощатая дверь на вершине.

Пред нею следы,а за ней-белизна.

И нет триумфальных здесь арок в помине,

а есть только ветер,мороз и снега...